# Convert java.util.GregorianCalender to java.lang.Integer?

Tags: groovy

Im using the followin script/function (named getQuarter) to get a last day of current quarter:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)/3 * 3 + 2);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
return cal.getTime();
```

And Im calling this function in my trigger which supposed to set this date every time when certain events occurs:

```
setAttribute('EffectiveDate', adf.util.getQuarter(today()))
```

But then the following error occurs when the trigger should start working:

> Exception in expression "util" global function getQuarter2(java.util.Date) : groovy.lang.MissingMethodException : No signature of method: java.util.GregorianCalendar.set() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer, java.math.BigDecimal) values: [2, 5] Possible solutions: set(int, int), get(int), set(int, int, int), set(java.util.Map), next(), isSet(int)

I figured out it needs the type GregorianCalendar converted to Integer, but how Im supposed to do this in my script? Any ideas?

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the values to `int`:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date());
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH as int, (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)/3 * 3 + 2) as int);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH as int, (cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) as int);
```

Comment: Okay, that resolved my previous problems, but now it asks for another cast? The error is: "Cannot create an object of type:java.sql.Date from type:java.util.Date with value:6/30/18 11:28 AM"

Comment: @Alwexistwo to java. what?

Comment: Okay, that resolved my previous problems, but now it asks for another cast? The error is: "Cannot create an object of type:java.sql.Date from type:java.util.Date with value:6/30/18 11:28 AM

Comment: My function returns typ "Date", if that helps

Comment: @Alwexistwo so think how you can convert `java.util.Date` to `java.sql.Date`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Java 8, can I suggest you us the new java.time classes?

Given todays date:

```
def date = LocalDate.now()
```

You can calculate the last day of the quarter by:

```
int quarter = YearMonth.from(date).get(IsoFields.QUARTER_OF_YEAR)
LocalDate lastDayOfQuater = date.withMonth(quarter * 3).with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth())
```